# Image wont display on show page

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

Im having trouble display an image that is saved in the database. on to a show page for a product. In the show page when I display a cupcake image the url  is changed. Ive pasted the code down below.

this is the route.js

```html
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Cupcake = require('../app/models/cupcakes');
var Cart = require('../app/models/cart');
var Order = require('../app/models/order')
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 var successMsg = req.flash('success')[0];
 Cupcake.find(function(err, cupcakes){
  if(!err){
     res.render('index', {
      title: 'Cupcakelicious',
      cupcakes: cupcakes,
      successMsg: successMsg,
      noMessage: !successMsg
     });
   // console.log(cupcakes);
  }else{
   return console.log(err);
  }
 });
});

router.get('/cupcake/:id', function(req, res, next) {
 var cupcake_id = req.param('id')
 console.log(typeof cupcake_id)
 console.log(cupcake_id)
 Cupcake.findOne({'_id': cupcake_id},function(err, cupcakes){
  if(!err){
   var cupcake =[];
   var c = cupcakes
   cupcake.push(c);
     res.render('show', {
      title: 'Cupcakelicious',
      cupcake: cupcake
     });
   // console.log("dfafsdsasdafdsagsd", cupcake);
  }else{
   return console.log(err);
  }
 });
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is the seed file with the image url

```html
var Cupcake = require('../models/cupcakes');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/salud')

var cupcakes = [
 new Cupcake({
  imageURL: 'Chocolate.jpg',
  Name: 'Chocolate cupcake',
  description: 'Freegan normcore vegan twee hell of. Trust fund vape edison bulb, health goth chartreuse pabst prism DIY tumeric distillery humblebrag normcore blue bottle coloring book.',
  price: 2.00
 }),
 new Cupcake({
  imageURL: 'vanilla.jpg',
  Name: 'Recess Peices cupcake',
  description: 'Freegan normcore vegan twee hell of. Trust fund vape edison bulb, health goth chartreuse pabst prism DIY tumeric distillery humblebrag normcore blue bottle coloring book.',
  price: 2.50
 })
];

var done = 0;
for (var i=0; i < cupcakes.length; i++){
 cupcakes[i].save(function(err, result){
  done++;
  if(done === cupcakes.length){
   exit();
  }
 });
}

function exit(){
 mongoose.disconnect();
}
```

this is where a cupcake is being displayed and not being found

```html
  <div class="row show-padding">
  <% for(var i=0; i < cupcake.length; i++){ %>
    <div class="center-div">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="<%= cupcake[i].image%>" alt="..." class="img-responsive show-img">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 div-fonts">
        <h1><%= cupcake[i].Name %></h1><br>
        <h2>$<%= cupcake[i].price %></h2><br>
        <h4>Cupcake info: </h4>
        <p><%= cupcake[i].description%></p><br>
        <hr align="left" width="50%">
        <a href="/add-cart/<%= cupcake[i]._id%>" role="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Add To Cart</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <% } %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide more information, such as mongoose schema and the string you're seeing instead of imageURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are saving the cupcakes as follows:

```
new Cupcake({
    imageURL: 'Chocolate.jpg',
    Name: 'Chocolate cupcake',
    description: 'Freegan normcore vegan twee hell of. Trust fund vape edison bulb, health goth chartreuse pabst prism DIY tumeric distillery humblebrag normcore blue bottle coloring book.',
    price: 2.00
}),
```

and accessing it

```
cupcake[i].image
```

so changing that to: `cupcake[i].imageURL` should do the trick, provided that it is the correct URL. I'm guessing you need to tweak the path tough, something like `http://your.domain/whereimagesaresaved/Chokolate.jpg`